# Determining Ambiguity of grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I read that no LL(1) grammar can be ambiguous.

Can we just make a LL(1) predictive parser table for a grammar to determine whether it's ambiguous? If the grammar is not LL(1), can we say that grammar is ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the grammar is not LL(1), can we say that grammar is ambiguous?

Euh, no. A grammar is unambiguous if for every word in its language there exists exactly one derivation-tree for it in the grammar.

Parsing is a way to find that derivation, given the string, preferably in some efficient way. Several classes of grammars were defined that have efficient parsing methods, for example LL(1) grammars.

A grammar can be non-LL(1), and still be unambiguous. For instance when we reverse an LL(1) grammar (that is, take the mirror image of the RHS of every production) the result still is unambiguous: mirroring the original unique derivation trees. But it cannot be parsed in an LL fashion, rather its reverse...

Comment: Suppose we have a grammar $A -> aA / b$ . If we reverse it then grammar is $A -> Aa / b$  . Here the grammar is unambiguous but not LL(1) because we have left recursion after reversing. Did you mean this ?

Comment: exactly! Hope that helps.

Comment: and by the way, thanks for the example.